# Rails 5.2 - Hybrid app (Active Storage + S3) active storage image url not generated on API side

Tags: api, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, bloburls

I created a hybrid Rails 5.2 app with views and API controller. I am allowing users to upload files thanks to active storage and S3.

My active storage service does generate the S3 image URL in my Rails views such as shown in the logs:

> Generated URL for file at key: HsBwx3LiGxmSJtDB2pu9nEiJ (https://[DOMAIN_NAME].s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/HsBwx3LiGxmSJtDB2pu9nEiJ?response-content-disposition=....

Unfortunately, on the API side, the image URL looks like this:

> /rails/active_storage/blobs/...

The idea is to consume this API in a Vue SPA.

**Model**

My model is pretty simple: 1 **Product** model with `has_one_attached :image`.

**Serializer**

I am using a serializer to present that image such as:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

...

def image
    rails_blob_path(object.image, only_path: true) if object.image.attached?  
end
```

**API Controller**

In my API controller, I am rendering as json my **Products** such as:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  render json: @products, each_serializer: ::ProductSerializer, status: :ok
end
```

**Config**

I am hosting on Heroku, all env. vars. are set.
My production settings look ok:

`config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

Testing on Postman and in my Vue app, still getting that rails blog URL and not the amazon one.

Appreciate your feedback on what I am missing here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. In my serializer, instead of:

```
def image
  rails_blob_path(object.image, only_path: true) if object.image.attached?  
end
```

I am using Active Storage `service_url` method such as:

```
def image
  object.image.service_url if object.image.attached?
end
```

Comment: url_for(object.image) will generate a permanent URL for the blob that points to the application. Upon access, a redirect to the actual service endpoint is returned.
This indirection decouples the public URL from the actual one, and
 allows for example mirroring attachments in different services for
 high-availability. The redirection has an HTTP expiration of 5 min.